# How to provide a link to access the dataset to share?

Tags: r, csv

I have a ".csv" dataset. I want to provide a link to access this dataset and put it in my project report. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a cloud. I usually do it with dropbox. Here is an example:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kjilkkskggi27vo/base_afastamentos.csv?dl=0

Comment: Thanks. It was a huge help.